# How to get the dense rank from the range that the conditions are matched without skipping if the range contains duplicates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, dense-rank

I'm now working on Google Sheet and I can't figure this problem out myself. I've tried many functions like IF(COUNTIF(....)) to find the unique values and SUMPRODUCT() to do the dense rank but all of this can't give me what I really want. I hope that you guys could help me fix this.

I have the sheet that contains the values with some duplicates like this :

[image]

I want to do the dense rank like this :

[image]

How can I do that in the Google Sheet?

Here is the link to the Google Sheet : [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XBW-5tgNEfLklwypNe5Xrvbo0Bk7o5faYfHZXxFkEss/edit?usp=sharing)

Please help me figure this out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share a link to the sheet in the screenshot or copy the data in an [anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) and share it here.

Comment: @z.. I just added the link to the sample of the data in the question. Please click the link. I gave the permission for everyone to edit. Please help me figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
   LET(class,A2:A,
       round,C2:C,
       score,D2:D,
       ranks,IFNA(
              BYCOL(
                {".",REGEXREPLACE(F1:I1,"(?s)Class (\w+)|(\w+) Round|.","$1$2")},
                LAMBDA(header,
                  LET(score_,IF(REGEXMATCH(class&round,header),score,),
                      XMATCH(score_,SORT(UNIQUE(score_),1,FALSE)))))),
       FILTER(ranks,class<>"")))
```

This formula is entered in cell `E2` and it produces the results for the whole table using the header `F1:I1` as reference for the classes/rounds to consider.

For each column, it's essentially sorting the unique scores and using XMATCH to return the rank. The order of the rank can be easily inverted by changing `FALSE` (inside the SORT function) to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this one and I'll give you feedback. First of all, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why I can't use your formula. It gave me ERROR. Could you please try this in the Google Sheets on your list or the link to my Google Sheets provided.

Comment: the formula is in the sheet you shared tab z cell E2.

Comment: Thank you @z.. I'll try to use it and give you feedback. Thank you so much for helping me.